# Bayesian Inference with a Normal Likelihood and Gamma Prior

Tags: bayesian, gamma-distribution, jags

I am fairly new to (the eye-opening world of) Bayesian inference and machine learning and I am stuck at a inference problem that is important to my current research, where I want to introduce Bayesian thinking into the field.

I want to estimate a the psoterior for a variable V that must remain positive. Now, first i want to use a conjugate normal updating of the mean to showcase the utility of Bayesian inference, and afterwards I wanted to move away from the conjugacy to further demonstrate what MCMC algorithms can do (e.g.via JAGS/STAN).

In the conjugate analysis, I'd assume both likelihood and prior to be normal. This is not a problem, since I know the closed form solution for updating the mean and variance of V.

If I switch the prior for V to be a gamma distribution (e.g. with scale a and shape b of 2) to keep the inference positive, I have a hard time defining the parameters of the model, since i have a shape and scale in the prior and a mean and variance in the posterior. Before i could just define the mean and variance as the parameters of the model, but with the gamma prior I can't get it to work in a similar way.

So in essence I have...

Prior:

p(V) ~ gamma (2,2)

Likelihood:

p(d|V) ~ normal(mean(V), sd(V))

I've been trying to code this in JAGS to obtain the posterior, but i struggle to formulate a suitable prior and likelihood for the inference problem. Is there someone proficient with e.g. JAGS here that can help me? Any help would be greatly appreciated, since I have to finish the paper until the end of this year.

My current (obviously unfinished) JAGS code looks as follows:

```
model_code <- "
model {
  v.bar <- (mean(ROE)-mean(r))/(mean(r)-mean(ROE)*(1-mean(k)))
  tau ~ dgamma(1,1)
  # Likelihood
  for (i in 1:N) {
    y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
    mu[i] <- v.bar
  }
}
"

value_data <- list("r" = c(0.08, 0.07, 0.043),
                  "k" = c(0.51, 0.45, 0.56),
                  "ROE" = c(0.1,0.08,0.06),
                  "y" = c(0.64, 0.38, 1.02),
                  "N" = 3)




library(rjags)
model <- jags.model(textConnection(model_code), data=value_data, n.chains=2)


update(model, n.iter=1000)
samples <- coda.samples(model, variable.names=c("mu", "tau"),
                        n.iter=1000)


summary(samples)
plot(samples)
```

Comment: For a conjugate analysis use inverse gamma as prior for sigma2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The conjugate analysis is not a problem for me though... that worked fine since i have closed-form solutions.

I used the formulae provided in https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf (and other sources) to perform that.

It's the inference with the gamma prior and normal likelihood that i can't get to work...

Comment: Hi: with that type of prior and likelihood, I would first try implementing an MCMC algorithm myself before using JAGS.  JAGS is powerful but fairly black boxy and would be best used as a check after you obtain some reasonable distribution using MCMC principles.

Comment: Hi and thank you! It definetely makes sense to try and code a suitable MCMC algorithm (e.g. metropolis hastings) myself, but I have a little bit of time pressure so I tried to skip that step. I guess I'll spend the day doing that.

@mlofton, do you have an idea how I could operationalize the parameters for the prior and likelihood here?

Comment: @Masel: I'm glad it helped. Unfortunately, it's been too long ( 10 years ) for me to remember the details but there's a good paper on MCMC by Chib and Greenberg. Let me see if I can find it and send the link. Here's the link. I hope it's helpful. https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Understanding-the-Metropolis-Hastings-Algorithm-Chib-Greenberg/e085f9a107c562a59b28c1136aee7a438387ac0f

Comment: Thank you! I'll go through it and see what that can do for me.